# can't get value in iframe from parent page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have tried the tutorial are there, but still could not work, what's wrong?

Parent Page Script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Parent</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.slim.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    var money = 20000;

    $("#iframe1").contents().find("#nominal").on("change keyup", function() {
        var input = $(this);

        // remove possible existing message
        if( input.next().is("form") )
            input.next().remove();

        // show message
        if( input.val() > money )
            alert('Hello');
    });
});
</script>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <iframe id="iframe1" src="iframe.html">
        </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Iframe script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Iframe</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="nominal" value="" />
    </body>
</html>
```

please tell me what was wrong, thanks advance.

Answer (score 0):

先加载`iframe`，等`load`完成后再监听`click`事件

First load `iframe`, such as `load` after the completion of the `click` event listener.

try this：

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Parent</title>
        <script src="//cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {

                $("#iframe1").attr("src","iframe.html");

                //iframe加载完毕以后执行的事件
                $("#iframe1").load(function(){
                    console.log('loaded...');
                    Handle();
                })

            });

            function Handle(){
                var money = 20000;
                $("#iframe1").contents().find("#nominal").on("change keyup", function() {
                    var input = $(this);
                    // remove possible existing message
                    if( input.next().is("form") )
                        input.next().remove();
                    // show message
                    if( input.val() > money )
                        alert('Hello');
                });
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <iframe id="iframe1">
    </iframe>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: can't work, the alert not showing. here's error log from console `jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).load is not a function @http://localhost/iframe/parent.html:12:17
resolve/</mightThrow@http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.slim.js:3508:21
resolve/</process<@http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.slim.js:3576:12
 undefined` and this `TypeError: $(...).load is not a function`

Comment: Change the jquery version, do not use 3, with version 2.2

Comment: same bro, not works `ReferenceError: $ is not defined` error log in console